# rendering components in div with react router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm working on a new project and am very new to React. We are using typescript(TSX). So far I have an `index.html` file with a div with an id of 'root'. I have a `main.tsx` file which I believe is for my main component. here is the code for that

```
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/main.d.ts"/>

require('file?name=[name].[ext]!../../index.html');

/*----------- STYLESHEETS -----------*/
require('flexboxgrid/css/flexboxgrid.css');

/*=============================================>>>>>
= MODULES =
===============================================>>>>>*/

import * as React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory  } from 'react-router';

/*----------- ROUTE COMPONENTS -----------*/
import Root from './common/root.tsx';
import Home from './home/home.tsx';
import Login from './login/login.tsx';
//
// /*= End of MODULES =*/
// /*=============================================<<<<<*/

 render((
   <Router history={browserHistory}>
     {/** ###### HOME ROUTE ###### */}
     <Route path="/" component={Root}>
       <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
       <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
     </Route>
     {/** ###### END HOME ROUTES ###### */}
   </Router>
 ), document.getElementById('root'));
```

I'm unsure of how to do my root.tsx file so that it shows up inside my root div. This is what I have so far for my root.tsx file.

```
"use strict";

import React from 'react';

class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>About page!</h1>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Root;
```

Comment: your code is confusing. what's the first block and what's the second? why is the first commented out?

Comment: Besides being commented out, the code looks fine as is. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: it was commented out because it didn't work at all and I was trying other things. uncommented this now. and yes, I have a few errors, the one that seems like it matters though is root.tsx?f149:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined

Comment: Can you try changing `import React from 'react'` to `import * as React from 'react';` in your root.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error description in your comment

> root.tsx?f149:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component'
>   of undefined

`React` is undefined at line 5 of `root.tsx` (below), so there must be something not working with your `import` statement:

`class Root extends React.Component`

I would suggest importing it the same way as you have done in your `main.tsx`.

```
import * as React from 'react'
```

instead of

```
import React from 'react';
```